# FineUploader S3 Compatible support

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I know that FineUploader works with Amazon S3 but there are many S3 compatible servers and we would like to evaluate FineUploader to be used with an S3 compatible server.

Has anyone done this ?  If so are there are configuration tips ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got you right here, but S3 is a service offered by AWS.  There is only "one" S3.

Using Fineuploader with S3 requires 3 parties:
- Browser (end-user)
- Server (hosted by a language of your choice: NodeJS, PHP, Python etc.)
- Amazon S3

If you'd like to try this, I advise you to visit www.fineuploader.com, and grab yourself a copy of the JQuery S3 Fineuploader.  It's offered without paying any money.

You can make it work first, and then pay for the commercial license later if you need that for commercial use.

In terms of configuration, they have a really good server-side demos in various languages here:
https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples

Client-side demos are in their website:
http://fineuploader.com/demos.html